# How to Structure This array, Separate Category and Product

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, reactjs

I have single array, I want to separate category and category Product

```
const product = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Cloth',
    cat: ['fashion', 'man', 'women']
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Shoes',
    cat: ['fashion']
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "hat",
    cat: ['man', 'fashion']
}]
```

How to Separate category value from Product array.

`const cat = ['fashion','man','women']`

How to Separate category and Product

```
const result = [{
    cat: 'fashion',
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Cloth'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Shoes'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "hat"
    }]
}, {
    cat: 'man',
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Cloth'
    }, {
        d: 3,
        name: "hat"
    }]
}, {
    cat: 'women',
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Cloth'
    }]
}]
```

How to develop this type of array please help me. Any one know please help me, Advance tanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

First answer:

```
let categories = [];
    const product = [
      { id: 1, name: "Cloth", cat: ["fashion", "man", "women"] },
      { id: 2, name: "Shoes", cat: ["fashion"] },
      { id: 3, name: "hat", cat: ["man", "fashion"] }
    ];

    product.forEach((p) => {
      p.cat.forEach((cat) => {
        if(!categories.includes(cat)) {
          categories.push(cat)
        }
      })
    })

console.log(categories) // ['fashion','man','women']
```

Comment: I see 3 loops for solving the task, I am sure there is a better way

Comment: how to do result array

Answer (score 0):

If you one to get All categories from product Array.

```
let allCategories = [];
product.forEach(p => {
    allCategories.push(...p.cat);
});
allCategories = [...new Set(allCategories)];
```

For second question I will use the result of first question:

```
allCategories.forEach(categorie => {
    result.push(
        {
            cat: categorie,
            products : product.filter(p => {
                if(p.cat.includes(categorie)) {
                    return {
                        id : p.id,
                        name : p.name
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    )
})
```